# Consulta Ajax y PHP

Tags: php, ajax, highcharts

Estimados.

Tengo un gráfico realizado con highchart, que toma datos de una base en mysql.
Necesito enviar dos datos mediante ajax, el rango de fechas, fecha de inicio y fin.
Esta es la porción de código del ajax.
El archivo se llama index.php

```
<script>
    $("#generarReporte").click(function(){   
        var fechaInicio = $("#fechaInicio").val();
        var fechaFin = $("#fechaFin").val();

        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "../libreria/ORM/reportes.php",
          data:  {fechaInicio:fechaInicio, fechaFin:fechaFin },    
          success: function(data){
            alert(data)
          }    
        });
        $("#opcion5").click();
    }); 
</script>
```

Cuando realizo un alert de data, pasa bien los valores, pero cuando ejecuto  $("#opcion5").click(); que es quien genera el gráfico no me muestra nada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo que recibe es reportes.php y este es el código de highcharts.

```js
<?php
        $fecInicio = $_POST['fechaInicio'];   
        $fecFin = $_POST['fechaFin'];
?>
  
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#opcion5").click(function(){      
        var theModal = $("#myModal").modal({
                            show: false
                            });   

        var chart = $("#container1").highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: "column"
            },
            title: {
                text: "Ventas Mensuales"
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: "Período consultado. Desde: <strong>"+'<?php echo $fecInicio; ?>'+ "</strong> Hasta: <strong>"+'<?php echo $fecFin; ?>'+"</strong>"
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: "category",
                labels: {
                    rotation: -45,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: "13px",
                        fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif"
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: "Pesos AR$"
                }
            },
            //establecemos los colores de las columnas por Mes
            colors: [
                "#4572A7", 
                "rgba(248, 44, 91, 0.61)", 
                "#89A54E", 
                "#80699B", 
                "#3D96AE", 
                "#DB843D", 
                "#92A8CD", 
                "#A47D7C", 
                "#B5CA92"
                ],

                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        colorByPoint: true
                    }
                },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: "Total del Mes: <b>$ {point.y:.2f}</b>"     
            },
            series: [{
                name: "Ventas por mes",
                data: [
                     <?php
                        include_once 'Conexion.php';
                        $objeto = new Conexion();
                        $conexion = $objeto->conectar();
                        $consulta = "SELECT MONTHNAME(fecha), sum(totalVenta) FROM ventas WHERE fecha BETWEEN '$fecInicio' AND '$fecFin' GROUP BY MONTH(fecha)";
                    
                        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
                        $resultado->execute();

                        while ($filas = $resultado->fetch()){ 
                      ?> 
                         ["<?php echo $filas["MONTHNAME(fecha)"] ?>", <?php echo $filas["sum(totalVenta)"] ?>],
                    
                        <?php 
                            }
                            $conexion=null;
                        ?>
                ],
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    //rotation: -90,
                    rotation: 0,
                    color: "#ffffff",
                    align: "center",
                    format: "{point.y:,.2f}", 
                    y: 30, // 10 pixels down from the top
                    style: {
                        fontSize: "13px",
                        fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif"
                    }
                }
            }]
        });

        theModal.on("shown",function(){
        }); 
        theModal.modal("show");
    });   

</script>
```

Dentro de reportes.php esta el código php que recibe con $_POST y la porción de javascript que les pase.

Comment: Añade el código en donde usas `$fecInicio` y `$fecFin` porque seguramente es donde está el problema.

Comment: Entiendo perfectamente tu explicación... Lo que no entiendo es...
Y cual es la pregunta??...

Comment: La pregunta es esa "¿Alguna sugerencia?" ya que no me muestra el gráfico. Al realizar el success de ajax e imprimir los valores con alert() me muestra que pasó los datos, pero en algún lugar no estoy haciendo bien las cosas, ya que no me muestra el gráfico.

Comment: Yo creo que esta todo mal. Si reportes.php es un php, este deberia procesarlo y crear un xml o un json para devolverlo. Eso lo haría en el php al finalizar así:
'echo $json;'
y despues ya se puede trabajar en la respuesta ajax de javascript.
Por otra parte, el alert te lo muestra porque lo interpreta como un string, no como código js o json. Si quieres que interprete el json así como lo tienes tal vez tengas que usar eval y tal vez así si te funcione como lo tienes pensado.
Pero deberias usar mvc y no revolver php, html, y js. Cada código debe ir en su propio archivo y tu lo estas revolviendo.

Comment: ¿Aparece algún error en la consola de JavaScript?¿Puedes compartir el código generado?

Answer (score 2):

Gracias por las respuestas.
Es verdad mezclé muchas cosas.

Es como dice el usuario abrahamhs.
Lo que hice fue separar de la siguiente forma y obtengo los datos que necesito.

Archivo PHP

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');  
include_once 'Conexion.php';

$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->conectar();


// Recepción de los datos enviados mediante POST desde el JS
$fecInicio = (isset($_POST['fechaInicio'])) ? $_POST['fechaInicio'] : '';
$fecFin = (isset($_POST['fechaFin'])) ? $_POST['fechaFin'] : '';

$consulta = "SELECT MONTHNAME(fecha), sum(totalVenta) FROM ventas WHERE fecha BETWEEN '$fecInicio' AND '$fecFin' GROUP BY MONTH(fecha)";

$resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
$resultado->execute();

$result = array();

while ($fila = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
   array_push($result, array($fila["MONTHNAME(fecha)"], $fila["sum(totalVenta)"])) ;         
}

print json_encode($result); //envio el array final el formato json a AJAX

$conexion=null;
```

En el archivo JS, envio el rango de fechas y recibo el json y lo paso a string con JSON.stringify...

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    
    var fechaInicio; 
    var fechaFin;
    
    $("#generarReporte").click(function(){   
        fechaInicio = $("#fechaInicio").val();
        fechaFin = $("#fechaFin").val();
        
        $.ajax({
          url: "../libreria/ORM/reportes.php",
          type: "POST",
          datatype:"json",    
          data:  {fechaInicio:fechaInicio, fechaFin:fechaFin },    
          success: function(data) {
             //recibo el json desde PHP y lo paso a string
              var valores = JSON.stringify(data);
              console.log(valores); 
          }
        });
           
    });     
});
```

En la consola, obtengo mi consulta, hago la validación, y es un json correcto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me falta ahora es pasar los resultados, guardados en "valores" al data de mi highcharts, supongo tengo que abrir otro tema.

Este es el código de mi gráfica en highcharts.

```js
 var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container1',
                type: "column"
            },
            title: {
                text: "Ventas Mensuales"
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ""
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: "category",
                labels: {
                    rotation: -45,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: "13px",
                        fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif"
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: "Pesos AR$"
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
            column: {
                    colorByPoint: true
                    }
                },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: "Total del Mes: <b>$ {point.y:.2f}</b>"     
            },
            series: [{
                name: "Ventas por mes",
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    //rotation: -90,
                    rotation: 0,
                    y: 30, // 10 pixels down from the top
                    style: {
                        fontSize: "13px",
                        fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif"
                    }
                },
                data:[
                   
                ]
            }]
        
    });
```

Comparto mi código con la comunidad. Cualquier sugerencia siempre es bienvenida.

Comment: No sé si esto debería ser una respuesta o una edición en la pregunta